# How can I get typescript working with plugins and systemjs?

Tags: jquery, typescript, systemjs, jspm

I configured **systemjs** and **typescript** with **JSPM**. It works if I don't use plugins.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.40"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "jspm": {
    "dependencies": {
      "ts": "github:frankwallis/plugin-typescript@^7.0.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "typescript": "npm:typescript@^2.0.7"
    }
  }
}
```

src/demo.ts

```
import $ from "jquery";

export default class Demo{
    private v : string;
    constructor(v : string){
        this.v = v;
    }
    method(){
        console.log(this.v);
        $("#list").append("<div>addedd div</div>");
    }
}
```

src/main.ts

```
import Demo from "./demo";

new Demo("string").method();
```

The problem is, webstorm recognizes jquery and it show the autocomplete for it but when i start the application the browser shows this error:

> Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading localhost:3000/jquery.js
>       Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading localhost:3000/jquery.js
>       Error loading localhost:3000/jquery.js as "jquery" from localhost:3000/src/demo.js

I've installed @types/jquery with the command

`npm install --save-dev @types/jquery`

**EDIT:**
config.js
It's generated by JSPM

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },

  map: {
  ....
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you show your SystemJS config?

Comment: Yes, I've added it. However it's generated by JSPM and it has got a lot of keys in the "map" object

Comment: Looks like you have installed typings for jquery (`@types/jquery`), but haven't installed jquery library itself - `jspm install jquery`

Comment: @Stubb0rn That did it! Thank you. I'm still having problem with webstorm, it recognizes jquery but it can't recognize any other library. So it gives error when I import for example lodash but it works at runtime!

Comment: Most of the libraries require typing information to be installed separately. Just like you did for `jquery` you need to install typings for `lodash` - `npm i -S @types/lodash`. You can read more about it here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/typescript/1542/importing-external-libraries#t=201703010836031788134

Comment: I've tried 
`typings install dt~lodash --global --save`
It works now! It seems that webstorm doesn't recognize DefinitelyTyped